# Override touchesBegan in protocol extension

Tags: swift, protocols

I'm trying to create a protocol so I can make some of my buttons to conform this protocol and play a sound when `touchesBegan` is called.

The protocol looks like this:

```
protocol AddSound: class {
    func addSound()
}

extension AddSound where Self: UIButton {
    func addSound() { print("play some sound") }
}

class CustomButton: UIButton, AddSound {

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        addSound()
    }
}
```

This works, but this means I have to manually override `touchesBegan` every time I use the protocol `AddSound`.

Is it somehow possible to override `touchesBegan` in the extension of `AddSound` or even an extension of `UIButton` itself, conforming the protocol `AddSound`?

**This doesn't work:**

```
extension AddSound where Self: UIButton {
    func addSound() { print("playing some sound") }

    // can't override touchesBegan
    func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        addSound()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Way 1

```
protocol AddSound: class {
    func addSound()
}

extension UIButton: AddSound {
    func addSound() { print("play some sound") }

    override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        addSound()
        print("touchesBegan")
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 80, height: 40))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
}
```

### Way 2

```
protocol AddSound: class {
    func addSound()
}

class MyButton: UIButton, AddSound {
    func addSound() { print("play some sound") }

    override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        addSound()
        print("touchesBegan")
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
....
var button = MyButton(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 80, height: 40))
....
```

### Result

Tap on button and you will see:

[image]

Comment: In your answer, all the `UIButton`'s will be affected and have `AddSound`. I only want the buttons which conforms to the protocol `AddSound` to make that sound though. I've read that protocol extensions aren't meant to override methods though, so I'll have to find other solutions for it.

Comment: Have you found a solution of your question?